# Is it possible to run an exe file linked with different version of dll?

Tags: opencv, dll

For example, I have a exe file which is compiled with OpenCV 1.0. If the dll is downward compatibility, how can I run the exe file in a machine with OpenCV 2.4.6?

Comment: why such an ability is required? if you are worried that the installed opencv might break the exe, you can statically linked it and the issue would be resolved

Answer (score 0):

you can't.

either supply the right dll version (1.0) or recompile the src code.